# mantis bug tracker word file attachment error at server side

Tags: mysql, database, open-source, database-administration, bug-tracking

2.12 version. I hosted it on godaddy server. it was working fine there suddenly it stopped uploading word attachments. on localhost there is no such issue faced. I want to know where could be this problem.

Here is the screenshoot of error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems the database is not enable for remote connections.

https://my.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-databases-remotely-in-cpanel-shared-hosting-16103

Comment: How can i enable the remote access to db on GoDaddy ?

Comment: I enabled direct access to db on godaddy but still facing same issue !

Comment: Here is the steps to enable remote login. 

https://my.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-databases-remotely-in-cpanel-shared-hosting-16103

Are you using static IP ? Also u need to add your public IP. Here you can get your public IP - https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address